# How to find the length of a string in R

Tags: r, string, unicode, string-length

How to find the length of a string (i.e., number of characters in a string) without splitting it in R? I know how to find the length of a list but not of a string.

And what about Unicode strings? How do I find the length (in bytes) and the number of characters (runes, symbols) in a Unicode string?

*Related Question:*

- [How to find the "real" number of characters in a Unicode string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481827/how-to-find-the-real-number-of-characters-in-a-unicode-string-in-r)

Comment: using evaluate() along with an anonymous function to return the last element of
| the vector c(8, 4, 0). Your anonymous function should only take one argument which should
| be a variable `x`.

Answer (score 495, accepted):

See `?nchar`. For example:

```
> nchar("foo")
[1] 3
> set.seed(10)
> strn <- paste(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = "")
> strn
[1] "NHKPBEFTLY"
> nchar(strn)
[1] 10
```

Comment: @hadley Indeed, or for that matter any character vector with one or more `NA`s. (Though this is documented to be so).

Comment: Or use `stri_length` from `stringi` - it works fine with NA's and it is faster :) Check my post!

Comment: As of 3.3.1 the base defaults are set to give `nchar(NA)
## [1] NA` : see [nchar RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/nchar)

Comment: Can I use the same method for a Unicode string? (see update)

Comment: @IgorChubin you should ask this as a new question, not edit an almost 2-year old one.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481827/

Answer (score 79):

Use `stringi` package and `stri_length` function

```
> stri_length(c("ala ma kota","ABC",NA))
[1] 11  3 NA
```

Why? Because it is the FASTEST among presented solutions :)

```
require(microbenchmark)
require(stringi)
require(stringr)
x <- c(letters,NA,paste(sample(letters,2000,TRUE),collapse=" "))
microbenchmark(nchar(x),str_length(x),stri_length(x))
Unit: microseconds
           expr    min     lq  median      uq     max neval
       nchar(x) 11.868 12.776 13.1590 13.6475  41.815   100
  str_length(x) 30.715 33.159 33.6825 34.1360 173.400   100
 stri_length(x)  2.653  3.281  4.0495  4.5380  19.966   100
```

and also works fine with NA's

```
nchar(NA)
## [1] 2
stri_length(NA)
## [1] NA
```

#### EDIT 2021

`NA` argument is no longer valid if you are using latest R version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the great library (it is your library if I understood it right). What about Unicode strings?

Comment: Works fine too. Look at this example:
`stri_length('\u0105')`  length is one, but...
`stri_numbytes('\u0105')`  2 bytes are used

Comment: This should be updated because `nchar()` now has an argument accounts for NA's: `allowNA = FALSE`

Comment: `nchar(NA)` now is `NA` - R 4.0.4

Comment: This answer is 7 years old ;) Thank you @Jabro, I've edited it and added info about NA.

Answer (score 31):

You could also use the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_length("foo")
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 28):

```
nchar("STRING")
```

Check out [this](http://r.seanrmccorkle.net/Doc/string_operations.html)

Answer (score 13):

The keepNA = TRUE option prevents problems with NA

```
nchar(NA)
## [1] 2
nchar(NA, keepNA=TRUE)
## [1] NA
```

Comment: As of 3.3.1 the base defaults are set to give `nchar(NA)
## [1] NA` : see [nchar RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/nchar)

Answer (score 9):

```
nchar(YOURSTRING)
```

you may need to convert to a character vector first;

```
nchar(as.character(YOURSTRING))
```

Comment: With the exception of a factor input, the coercion is performed by `nchar`. For factor inputs, `nchar` will throw an error and hence you will need to do the conversion first as you show.